# How to update scope variable using service

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

i have two controllers, the data in the first controller will be updated by click functions in the second controller. I am using service to communicate between controllers and not getting the expected result. whats wrong i am doing

link: http://jsbin.com/hozabigedu/1/

Answer (score 1):

Well, you had several issues. First, I changed your `data` to be an object and to have a boolean as a property, rather than have itself be a boolean. This is good practice if you want to share info using a service. It's better that you share an object so that different controllers share the same reference. Primitives are problematic for that scenario. So here's the new service:

```
app.service('testservice', function(){

  var data={}; //Changed here


  getDataText = function() {
    return data;
  };

  setDataText= function(val) {
    data.text = val; //And changed here
    return data;
  };

  return {
    getDataText: getDataText,
    setDataText: setDataText

  };

});
```

Another issue is that your controller called the wrong function, it should be `getDataText()`:

```
$scope.inputText = testservice.getDataText();
```

And lastly, you forgot to close the `divs` of the `click` elements, so the click 2 events bubbled up to the click 1 events thus showing right after hiding, so replace the 2nd controller div with this one:

```
<div ng-controller="secondController">

    <div ng-click="showDiv();"><a href="#">click1</a></div>
      <br/>
      <br/>
    <div ng-click="hideDiv();"><a href="#">click2</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```